# cast cx_vec element to double complex armadillo c++

Tags: c++, armadillo

I've got a vector `cx_vec A(2);`. I'd like to pick the first element and get its argument. I have found no function in armadillo to do this so I am trying to do `arg( A.row(0) )` however `arg` expects a `double complex`. Is there any way to convert back and forth from `cx_vec` to `double complex` similarly to `arma::as_scalar` for `double`?

I have tried casting it but it doesn't work.

Please note I am using `#include <complex.h>` instead of `#include <complex>` since I need some of its definitions that apparently are not in the latter (i.e. `I`).

EDIT: thanks to `@kirbyfan64sos` I realized that is not a good idea to use `complex.h` but still can't get a way to convert an element of `arma::cx_vec` from to `std::complex<double>`.

Comment: `complex.h` != `complex`; the latter is the C++11 complex type, the former is for C11, which it technically completely different. You should be using `complex`.

Comment: @kirbyfan64sos thanks, I have changed to `complex` but how to get a `std::complex<double>` out of an element of `cx_vec`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
arma::cx_vec A(2);

// ... fill A with stuff ...

double x = std::arg( A(0) );
```

Comment: @Thanks for pointing that out I was having problems because usually I do `A.row(0)` instead.

Comment: The function arma::arg(A) is now supported in Armadillo version 8.600. You can get the same result with `arma::as_scalar(arma::arg(A.row(0)))`